# SPSS and ordinary least squares

Tags: spss

I am doing regression and I am using [SPSS/PASW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPSS). But it doesn't seem to support Ordinary Least Squares, it only has Partial least Squares and 2-stages Least Squares. Any suggestions about what to do?

Answer (score 2):

[This link](http://www.spss.com/software/statistics/regression/) mentions SPSS weighted least squares.  I think if you make all the weights equal to 1.0 you've got what you're calling "ordinary" least squares.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Barry - OLS is 'standard' in SPSS/PASW - the least squares method is used in standard linear regressions and in PASW if you select "Analyze>Regression>Linear" that will give you what you are calling OLS.

This is taken from SPSS/PASW's help documents - it does not directly say OLS under standard linear regression, but infers OLS via this document...

> "Standard linear regression models
>   assume that errors in the dependent
>   variable are uncorrelated with the
>   independent variable(s). When this is
>   not the case (for example, when
>   relationships between variables are
>   bidirectional), linear regression
>   using ordinary least squares (OLS) no
>   longer provides optimal model
>   estimates. Two-stage least-squares
>   regression uses instrumental variables
>   that are uncorrelated with the error
>   terms to compute estimated values of
>   the problematic predictor(s) (the
>   first stage), and then uses those
>   computed values to estimate a linear
>   regression model of the dependent
>   variable (the second stage). Since the
>   computed values are based on variables
>   that are uncorrelated with the errors,
>   the results of the two-stage model are
>   optimal."

Answer (score 0):

SPSS should default to OLS unless you are doing something to make it switch; I think that the problem is that the default is assumed, and not explicitly mentioned.